# Granting access to sys objects via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I want to allow a user to execute a stored procedure. The stored procedure selects data from `sys.indexes`.

However, giving `EXECUTE` permissions to the stored procedure does not work, I still get the error

> The user does not have permission to perform this action.

due to the user not having access to `sys.indexes`.

What can I do (without giving the user direct `SELECT` access to the sys.indexes table)?

Comment: That's odd. Are you using dynamic SQL or something? Normally, if the procedure's owner has permission on the underlying object (in this case sys.indexes), exec on the proc is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to grant permission to the user to access that table:

[GRANT System Object Permissions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187797.aspx)

`GRANT SELECT ON sys.indexes TO yourUser`

If you don't want to grant acces to that table, you can use the ownership chaining. The problem is that the owner for `sys.indexes` is `securityadmin`:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.schemas AS S
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS SP 
ON S.principal_id = SP.principal_id
WHERE S.name = 'sys'
```

So, the problem is that you need to create a procedure whose owner is `securityadmin`. To do so, you can create it and then use the ol' good [sp_changeobjectowner](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177519(v=sql.110).aspx). As you can see in the docs it's deprecated, but there are other alternatives.

Comment: I don't want them to be able to select from that table without using the stored procedure, like you would usually control security with normal tables.

Comment: Oops, I was blind when I read your question.I've updated my answer. Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually you didn't notice that part of my question because I only edited it in after you answered :) Anyway, your answer makes sense but I can't make it work. If try to transfer ownership to 'securityadmin' using sp_changeobjectowner, it says "Database principal or schema 'securityadmin' does not exist in this database." I can transfer to 'db_securityadmin', but that results in the same problem as I originally had. I guess 'db_securityadmin' is not the same as 'securityadmin'...